# Access const value assigned inside OnInit method on some event

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to log name vale on click event but not able to. please advise.
Inside .ts

```
export class ScrolldemoComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
        const name = "test";
      }

      myEvent(event) {
        console.log(name);
      }

    }
```

inside html

```
<button (click)="myEvent()">My Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it at the component level

```
name:string = 'test'
 ngOnInit() {
    this.name = "test";
  }

  myEvent(event) {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

"const" create variables that are block-scoped i.e they only exist within the innermost block that surrounds them.

So,you will not get the value of name outside "ngOnInIt".Please define it at the component level as suggested by Aravind.

Answer (score 0):

Please add some diffrent value to the oinit(name) the compiler will take the outside function value. It will not work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).